# Blackberry Date Format?

Tags: date, blackberry

I'm receiving date response encoded: 1367726400000 from a webservice.

How can I make it in dd-mm-yy Format?

Comment: this is time in milliseconds ?

Comment: Yes, Its in millisecond.

Comment: convert the string to long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code-

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
System.out.println("Now: " + sdf.format(new Date(1367726400000 )));
```